# Should I use ruby threads or just not use ruby altogether for threading?

Tags: java, ruby, multithreading

I have a choice to develop an app which will rely heavily on threading (up to to 200). I know I can use other Ruby interpreters for threading such as JRuby. But there are 2 things:

1) Jruby doesn't support 1.9 yet, so that is a no. Is there any other non-green thread interpreter that supports at least 1.9 as that is a prerequisite for me if I use Ruby.

2) Even using an interpreter such as Jruby, would I really get decent thread perfomance that I can get in Java? Perhaps I should just use Java for this application.

**Note**: this isn't an attempt at  subjective discussion. It is for advice regarding thread performance only. Also, this isn't Java vs Ruby or anything of that nature. I am newer to Ruby and hoping to clear this up for my own benefit, thanks.

Comment: I thought that JRuby threads mapped directly to JVM threads.  If that's true, even though your JRuby isn't "1.9", it ought to use native threads (if your JVM uses native threads).  Oh, and can you give us an idea of what your application is doing?  Sometimes there are alternatives to threads that you might not have thought about.

Comment: Network I/O/Http. Similar to JMeter. Each thread is created for that reason. Performance is pretty important. And so I like to program in Ruby, if i can I would like to do it for this project.

Comment: Side issue: 200 threads? So you have a 200 core machine? Cool.

Comment: Earwicker, I won't mean to be rude but you do need to read about this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computer_science%29#I.2FO_and_scheduling  ...I/O threads are blocked, thus not consuming any core while in that state. Since network is IO intesive, a LOT of blocking occurs, allowing 200 threads on a single core to be pretty common since I/O blocks take so much time compared to when the thread is actually active on a CPU.

Comment: Yeah, I know. You need to read up on thread pools and figure out why scalable systems use them instead of creating a huge number of threads with nothing to do. While a thread is blocked on IO, it's doing nothing except taking up ~1MB of address space for its stack.

Comment: @Earwicker: You are right. So do you recommend thread pooling for an app which is basically JMeter/each task consists of 1 http request ?

Comment: You may not benefit from threads at all. If you are writing something to simulate a heavy load on an HTTP server, that basically involves connecting a socket, sending some stuff, reading stuff back, closing the socket, lots of times in parallel. Very little CPU, lots of IO. So you may not benefit from starting more than one thread. A single thread could manage 200 state machines that each cycle through connect, send, receive... over and over. The key is to use asynchronous interface. Here's a simple example: http://www.example-code.com/ruby/async_sockets.asp

Comment: NB those examples loop/sleep until the state changes! Obviously that's not the right thing to do. You want a callback to fire when the state changes (e.g. data arrives on the socket) so you can advance the state of the corresponding connection.

Answer (score 6):

You should really benchmark it.

Are your threads going to be doing a lot of simultaneous computation? Then you'd probably need native threads. But if you are going to be waiting for IO all the time, then maybe Ruby's green threads are fine.

Even with this advice, you should cook up a small test program and see if the straightforward way (just using Ruby 1.9) will work.

Comment: If I can get some time to I will try and post back the results.